# Put authors information in parallel

Tags: overleaf

I am a newbie to LaTeX. I want to put 2 students name as well as their email addresses in parallel as in a 2-column table under the title "Students" centered horizontally. So does the "Supervisor" section.

My current attempt was:

```
\author{
Students:\\[5pt]
\NAMEONE{}\\
\href{student1@gmail.com}{student1@gmail.com}
\and
\NAMETWO{}\\
\href{student2@gmail.com}{student2@gmail.com} \\[15pt]
Supervisor:\\[5pt]
\SUPERVISOR{} \\[30pt]
}
```

This gave me:

[image]

But what I want is something like this:

[image]

Can anyone give me some guidance to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be mentioned that many publications require custom document classes (e.g. IEEEtran) which often have special features to handle multiple authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a `tabular`:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{title}
\author{%
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}c}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Students:}\\[5pt]
       Name 2                                               & Name 2 \\
       \href{mailto:student1@gmail.com}{student1@gmail.com} & \href{mailto:student2@gmail.com}{student2@gmail.com} \\
       \\[10pt]
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Supervisor:}\\[5pt]
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name}
    \end{tabular}
 }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```